# How to correctly convert TS to JS using AssetConverter in Yii2 framework

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I using Yii2 framework version 2.0.32 basic
PHP version 7.2.30
So I tried use Assets for convert typescript but I've got error.

My coposer.json:

```
{
  "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
  "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
  "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
  "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.32",
    "yidas/yii2-bower-asset": "~2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "johnitvn/yii2-ajaxcrud": "*",
    "johnitvn/yii2-rbac-plus": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
    "lajax/yii2-translate-manager": "1.*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-develop",
    "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
    "mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php": "^1.3",
    "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "~1.1",
    "ext-calendar": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "^1.0@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-bootstrap4-dropdown": "@dev",
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.4@dev",
    "yiisoft/yii2-twig": "^2.0@dev",
    "facebook/webdriver": "^1.7.1",
    "doctrine/collections": "^1.6.4",
    "skeeks/yii2-mobile-detect": "dev-master",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.1@dev",
    "sweelix/yii2-webpack": "dev-master",
    "twig/intl-extra": "3.x-dev"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "facebook/webdriver": "^1.7.1",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
    "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3",
    "ext-xsl": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
      "setPermission": [
        {
          "runtime": "0777",
          "web/assets": "0777",
          "yii": "0755"
        }
      ],
      "generateCookieValidationKey": [
        "config/web.php"
      ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
      "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
      "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
  }
}
```

I have using the following code:

-- config file:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
    'converter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
        'commands' => [
            'less' => ['css', 'lessc {from} {to} --no-color'],
            'ts' => ['js', 'tsc --out {to} {from}'],
        ],
    ],
    'bundles' => [
        'mdm\admin\AdminAsset' => false,
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => false,
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => false,
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => false,
    ],
```

];

-- Assets class:

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
use yii\web\View;

class DemoAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $js = [
        'js/params/demo.js',
        'js/params/greeting.ts'
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public  $jsOptions = ['position' => View::POS_HEAD];
}
```

But I always getting error:

> Exception – yii\base\Exception AssetConverter command 'tsc --out
> "c:/WinNMP/www/planning/web/js/params/greeting.js"
> "c:/WinNMP/www/planning/web/js/params/greeting.ts"' failed with exit
> code : STDOUT:
>
> STDERR:

Thanks in advence.

Comment: Maybe give this a try https://github.com/pgaultier/yii2-webpack